# PHP Fatal errors on PhpStorm for Laravel Project using WampServer when run/debug

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, phpstorm

I have tried to run/debug multiple projects on PhpStorm (two of them are imported, one is created on phpstorm) Each of them gives me (different) PHP Fatal errors when I run or debug.

---

This is the first error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Tests\Common\Cache\CacheTest' not found in C:\wamp64\www\bodisatva\vendor\doctrine\cache\tests\Doctrine\Tests\Common\Cache\ApcCacheTest.php on line 10
```

Problem is that CacheTest exists.

---

The second project:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Tests\DoctrineTestCase' not found in C:\wamp64\www\larasocial\vendor\doctrine\inflector\tests\Doctrine\Tests\Common\Inflector\InflectorTest.php on line 8
```

Again, it exists.

---

Project that I completely set up on PhpStorm for testing.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Tests\Behat\Gherkin\Keywords\KeywordsTest' not found in C:\wamp64\www\larazine\vendor\behat\gherkin\tests\Behat\Gherkin\Keywords\ArrayKeywordsTest.php on line 8
```

Different and same.

---

Am I missing something? I tried to google these errors only to find specific (but probably outdated as I had even more errors trying them) solutions.

Comment: Did you try `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

How did you configure **PHPUnit in File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | PHPUnit**? Is it PHPunit 5 or 6? You might want to attach a screenshot of your config here.

Are there any inspection errors in *C:\wamp64\www\larasocial\vendor\doctrine\inflector\tests\Doctrine\Tests\Common\Inflector\InflectorTest.php* on line 8, e.g. **DoctrineTestCase** or **TestCase** are highlighted?

Comment: Try to open C:\wamp64\www\larasocial\vendor\doctrine\inflector\tests\Doctrine\Tests\Common\Inflector\InflectorTest.php in IDE - check the file for any errors highlighted by the editor

Comment: Nothing is highlighted.

Comment: well, you might try to archive a sample project and attach it here